# update trigger to maintain correct url in field

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am seeking a short term solution while I work out why a synchronisation is setting one field wrong in a table
I prepared a trigger and would welcome some comment on it, and any necessary corrections or better strategies.

```
     CREATE TRIGGER urlcorrect AFTER INSERT ON sym_node
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     IF NEW.sync_url= 'http://wrongaddress' THEN
     UPDATE sym_node SET sync_url= "http://123.456.7.89:1234/etc";
     END IF;;
     END$
     delimiter;
```

thanks
David

Comment: Better strategies in what? You haven't explained your issue

Comment: For the moment, I would like to put in this trigger. MySQL Workbench believes it has errors in it. As this is my first trigger, the errors are not clear to me, despite my research.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is wrong in various ways.

First of all, I think you want a BEFORE trigger so that you can fix the row before it gets into your table.

Secondly, this:

```
UPDATE sym_node SET sync_url= "http://123.456.7.89:1234/etc";
```

would update every `sync_url` in the `sym_node` table and that's not what you want. And I don't think MySQL will let you UPDATE a table inside a trigger on that table (someone correct me if I'm wrong on this please). Also, you should be using single quotes for string literals even though MySQL will let you use double quotes, don't pick up bad habits from MySQL lax behavior. You want to:

```
set new.sync_url = 'http://123.456.7.89:1234/etc';
```

Putting all that together, you get this:

```
delimiter $
create trigger urlcorrect before insert on sym_node
for each row begin
    if new.sync_url = 'http://wrongaddress' then
        set new.sync_url = 'http://123.456.7.89:1234/etc';
    end if;    
end;
$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Mu
Many thanks for that advice. I don't need to add to my bad habits.
I also appreciate you pointing out that the UPDATE statement would cause all the rows to get that value. Not at all what I want.

Comment: This worked well, with one change. The data is only two rows. There are no inserts, only updates. So the trigger should be BEFORE UPDATE... and the rest is right.